# Resolving path with bash

Tags: bash, sh, readlink

On I am on MacOS, but looking for a cross-platform solution that will also work on *nix. Simple question, how can I resolve this path with bash a script?

```
/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/../lib/node_modules/suman/cli/cli.sh
```

This path is made up of two pieces which I have in hand:

```
/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin
```

and

```
../lib/node_modules/suman/cli/cli.sh
```

what is the best way to get an absolute path that represents the resolution of those two paths?

Note that my Mac has `readlink` on it, but it doesn't appear to be the same utility as that on *nix machine. Most importantly, my `readlink` utility does not have the `-f` option that *nix utility probably does, so I can't seem to use that.

Comment: See: [Getting the Current/Present working directory of a Bash script from within the script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/3776858)

Comment: Just tried a few things from there - can you elaborate on what answer in there you think will help me?

Comment: I suppose the first answer can help you in your script: `DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"`. I have no way to test them with MacOS and bash.

Comment: For my purpores, I can get the same value from simply $(dirname "$0"), that's not what I need I don't think

Comment: Please add output of `dirname "$0"` from your script and your desired output to your question.

Comment: Given my answer, do you now know  what I am looking for, if you didn't already?

Comment: Why does it need "resolved"? `/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/../lib/node_modules/suman/cli/cli.sh` is a perfectly fine path that refers to the same file as `/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/lib/node_modules/suman/cli/cli.sh`

Comment: Idk depends on the program interpreting the path, not all programs will be able to interpret it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` is perfectly able to handle such a task. Taking inspiration from the main question comments, you can do something like this :

```
MYPATH=/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin/../lib/node_modules/suman/cli/cli.sh
RESOLVED="$(cd $(dirname $MYPATH) && pwd)/$(basename $MYPATH)"
```

- `dirname` returns the path without the file name at the end
- `cd` changes to the directory we got, and `pwd` displays the current directory.
- `basename` is the opposite of `dirname`, and returns the name of the file.
- as all of those instructions were executed in a subshell, we didn't actually `cd` in our main script

EDIT: I gave this answer using tools i was familiar with. However, I've just taken a look at the `readlink` utility you mentioned in your question. It seems to work just fine for me with the `-m` option. Is this flag available on mac ?

```
readlink -m /home/myusername/Documents/test_dir/dir_1/../dir_2/test.sh
> /home/myusername/Documents/test_dir/dir_2/test.sh
```

Comment: Idk depends on the program interpreting the path, not all programs will be able to interpret it correctly

Answer (score -1):

For the moment, I solved it this way

```
DIRN="/Users/Olegzandr/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/bin"

EXECDIR="../lib/node_modules/suman/cli/cli.sh"

RESOLVED=$(node -e "var path = require('path'); process.stdout.write(path.resolve('$DIRN/$EXECDIR'))");
```

Frankly, bash is *not* cool at all. The fact that I have to resort to these kind of shenanigans is ridonkulous.

Comment: You are overcomplicating the issue. `bash` is perfectly able to handle such a task. As @Cyrus pointed out in the main question comments, you can do the following : `MYPATH=/some/stuff/../otherstuff/a.sh; RESOLVED="$(cd $(dirname $MYPATH) && pwd)/$(basename $MYPATH)"`

Comment: Let me try your solution.

Comment: Alright your idea seems to work, and I see why it does, feel free to add it as an answer

Comment: bash is perfectly capable of solving the problem (with four utiltiies => dirname, pwd, cd, and basename) LOL fml

Comment: to be fair, I answered using tools I was familiar with. However, `readlink` seems to work very well with the `-m` flag (have a look at my edited answer). Is this flag available on mac ?

Comment: readlink should work, but apparently not all Mac's have it installed out of the box